# In Laravel 5.8, how do you define a model factory in a package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-testing

I can't seem to find any good and up to date resources on how to accomplish this.

I basically want to do this from within my package:

```
$factory->define(MyPackage\About\Models\About::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        "title" => $faker->text(5),
        "image" => $faker->imageURL,
        "content"   => $faker->text,
        "metadata_id" => null,
    ]; 
});
```

Can this be done?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11881#issuecomment-261688266

Comment: Alternatively it might be possible to simply include the package factories somewhere within the application factories.